# Audio player for Windows meeting specific requirements

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, mp3

I am looking for an audio player for Windows that meets specific requirements.

***Requirements***

1. Very fast to load and exit (similar to Calc that is included with Windows)
2. Reasonably low memory footprint (IOW, not a memory hog)
3. Simple GUI focusing on playing audio files (not editing them)
4. Plays MP3 and WAV audio files
5. Adjustable playback speed (e.g. 1.5x, 2x, etc.)
6. Starts "clean" each time (IOW, does not show the name of the previous files played)
7. Uninstalls cleanly
8. Does not access internet at all, or at least without obvious consent
9. Compatible with Windows 7
10. Gratis

***Preferences (none required)***

1. Portable
2. Pitch compensation for adjustable playback speed
3. Optionally view file details (such as compression details or ID3 tags)

***Not Needed (but fine if it has one or more of these features)***

1. Playlists
2. Skins
3. Audio editing
4. Tag editing
5. Format conversion

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the [*TimeStretch Player*](https://29a.ch/timestretch/) (by Jonas Wagner) is what you are looking for. It's a simple, browser-based app that plays audio files. The files need to be loaded from your disk, it does not play from an URL, though.

[image: TimeStretch Player GUI]

- Supports mp3 and wav, basically any audio formats your browser does
- Offline installable as PWA (Completely runs offline. Current version also has no Facebook ingetration, I checked the network connections)
- free
- Offers speed and pitch adjustments

It also ticks all your other requirements.

Comment: Thanks Marcel.  What is the official URL?  A search found a few different possibilities, but if you know the official URL, that will be most helpful.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Thanks for pointing this out, I added the link and credit. It runs directly in the browser. On his blog, https://29a.ch/2015/12/06/time-stretching-audio-javascript Jonas explains some inner workings.

Comment: Thank you Marcel. I appreciate it!